# My eclipse detects an error 

Tags: swing, filefilter

whats wrong with my my, the FileFilter says its cant istantiate

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

import java.io.File;    

public class fileChooser2 extends Object {
public fileChooser2() {
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
   // Note: source for ExampleFileFilter can be found in FileChooserDemo,
   // under the demo/jfc directory in the JDK.
   FileFilter filter = new FileFilter();
   filter.addExtension("jpg");
   filter.addExtension("gif");
   filter.setDescription("JPG & GIF Images");
   chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
   int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
   if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
           chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());


}
}
}
```

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1):

[`FileFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) is an `abstract` class (which means it cannot be instantiated), you must extend it. See the [`FileNameExtensionFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html) for a concrete implementation of `FileFilter`. You might also want to see the [tutorial on how to use `FileChooser`s which has a section on custom `FileFilter`s](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters)

---

If you use the `FileNameExtensionFilter`, you could change this

```
FileFilter filter = new FileFilter();
filter.addExtension("jpg");
filter.addExtension("gif");
filter.setDescription("JPG & GIF Images");
```

to this

```
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
```